# Swift, Tuples issue #2

Tags: swift, tuples

Sorry about the last thread where I posted this question by accident! Here it is. I received a response from someone (Their response is at bottom of page) and unfortunately it did not work. Thanks in advance!

Create a variable named result and assign it the tuple returned from function greeting. (Note: pass the string "Tom" to the greeting function.)

```
func greeting() -> (language: String, greeting: String, name: String) {

    let language = "English"
    let greeting = "Hello"
    let name = "Tom"

    return (language, greeting, name)
}
var result = greeting()
```

Error = Your function needs to return a tuple with elements named 'greeting' and 'language'.

Now this solution below tells me that my variable has the wrong value in it, but I can't figure out how to pass it "Tom" to the greeting function because I keep getting an error.

```
func greeting() -> (language: String, greeting: String) {

    let language = "English"
    let greeting = "Hello"
    return (language, greeting)
}
var result = greeting("Tom")
```

Response I got in the last thread is below. I still get the error message saying that I need to assign the return value of greeting to result.

```
func greeting(name:String) -> (language: String, greeting: String) {

    let language = "English"
    let greeting = "Hello " + name + "!"
    return (language, greeting)
}
var result = greeting("Tom").greeting
```

Comment: Your first block works for me in a playground. The second one doesn't work because you've declared the function as taking no parameters, and yet you are calling it with the parameter "Tom". The third one works for me in a playground.

Comment: Yes i'm getting the same results with the third block, it should work. But on the Treehouse course i'm getting the error message saying "You need assign the return value of the 'greeting' function to 'result"

Answer (score 0):

The task is

> Create a variable named result and **assign it the tuple returned from function greeting**.

What you do in the last block is

```
var result = greeting("Tom").greeting
```

what I would expect you to do is

```
var result = greeting("Tom")
```